# findOneAndUpdate gives back null if user is not updated (due to conditions)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If you read my code, you'll see that the user is not updated if the id given by a request matches an element in the `Friends` array of a document (due to the `$not` operator). Therefore, If the Users are found and not updated, the result (myDoc, otherDoc) given back is null. I would like to still get both documents whether they have been updated or not. I checked the mongoose docs but can't seem to find the solution for that.

```
promise.all([
 User.findOneAndUpdate( {id: req.body.myId, Friends: { $not: { $elemMatch: { id: req.body.id }}}}, {$addToSet: { Friends: { id:   req.body.id, gender: req.body.gender, emoji: res.locals.myEmoji }}}), 
  User.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.body.id, Friends: {$not: { $elemMatch:    {id: req.body.myId }}}}, {$addToSet:  { Friends: { id: req.body.myId,    gender: req.body.myGender, emoji: res.locals.friendEmoji }}})])
 .spread(function (myDoc, otherDoc){


  ///gives back null if user is not updated

 }).catch(function (err){

  return res.status(400).send(err)

 });
```

Edit: Is there some kind of mongoose plugin useful for this?   ....

Comment: can you show your user schema?

Comment: did you check to see if your query works on a regular find. If it return null on a regular find and not an update maybe your query isn't doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I checked my friend. It finds it just fine. Ravi.. this is my schema var userSchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  gender: String,

Friends:  [attributes]

});

Comment: attributes is just a child schema (no need to worry about that, just that friends is an array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get back the updated document after findOneAndUpdate add argument called new and set it to true, something like.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate( {
  id: req.body.myId, Friends: { $not: { $elemMatch: { id: req.body.id }}}
},{
  $addToSet:{Friends:{ id: req.body.id, gender: req.body.gender,emoji: res.locals.myEmoji}}
}, {
  new: true
}),
```